# prevent shortcuts with wpf webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf

hey I have a problem with my wpf webbrowser. I dont want that you can press shortcuts like "CRTL + N" for a new tab for example. I already found out how to do it, but if I want to handle more shortcuts it will only prevent the last one. I know that this will be very simple but I dont know how to fix it at the moment. Here is my code:

```
e.Handled = e.Key == Key.N && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control; 
        e.Handled = e.Key == Key.O && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control;
        e.Handled = e.Key == Key.OemMinus && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control;
        e.Handled = e.Key == Key.OemPlus && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control;
        e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Subtract && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control;
        e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Add && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to OR together your conditions.

```
e.Handled = ((e.Key == Key.N) && (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)) ||
    ((e.Key == Key.O) && (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)) ||
    ((e.Key == Key.OemMinus) && (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)) ||
    ((e.Key == Key.OemPlus) && (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)) ||
    ((e.Key == Key.Subtract) && (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)) ||
    ((e.Key == Key.Add) && (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control));
```

As Modifier CTRL appears to be common, this can be separated out from the keys & the simplified code would be something like

```
e.Handled = (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) &&
    ((e.Key == Key.N) || (e.Key == Key.O) || (e.Key == Key.OemMinus) || ...... )
```

Note that I have added brackets that some people will say are unnecessary, but I prefer them for readability.