# How I disable Keyboard shortcuts in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a window with a UserControl that contains a WebBrowser control. This browser has a form where the user needs to type in some entries and hit submit. However, In the Main Window, I'm allowing the users to hit a key and open a user control. Like in this example, when they hit the "R" Key, it should open the Webbrowser control. That's working fine. But when the user is in the form inside the WebBrowser control and are typing , if they hit the "R" key, it reopens the control. If they hit some other key tied to another control, it opens that.

Here's the code for the button :

```
           <RadioButton GroupName ="NAV" x:Name="Report_BTN" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" Command="{Binding ReportCommand}"  Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Foreground="White"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding ReportEnabled}" Template="{DynamicResource Nav_Tab}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="Images/ReportIcon.png" Height="50" Width="auto" Margin="20,0" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" />
                    <Label Content="_Report" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
                </StackPanel>
            </RadioButton>
```

As you can see, in the Label, I have the Content as "_Report", which means, if an user hits the "R" key, it opens it.

How do I disable it when the user is inside the webbrowser control, allowing them to type?

Adding more code:

This is the code in the MainWindow to add usercontrols:

```
    <Grid x:Name="UserControlGrid"  Width="Auto" Height="auto" Margin="100,40,0,0">
            <ScrollViewer Width="Auto" Height="auto" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewsToShow}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Grid IsItemsHost="True" Width="auto" Height="auto"></Grid>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Code in the ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableObject> ViewsToShow
    {
        get
        {
            return viewsToShow;
        }
        set
        {
            viewsToShow = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ViewsToShow");
        }
    }

    public ICommand ReportCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(() => Report()); }
    }

    public void Report()
    {
        ViewsToShow.Clear();
        ViewsToShow.Add(new ReportViewModel());
    }
```

It's not really a duplicate, since the thread posted as duplicate didn't work for me.
Sorry if this is a long winded question.

Thank you

Comment: How and where do you open the control? Please post some sample code.

Comment: @mm8: added code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent shortcuts with wpf webbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724219/prevent-shortcuts-with-wpf-webbrowser)